# Email newsletter unsubscribe link is not working?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, email-templates, newsletter

I am using this to generate URL for unsubscribe in email template

```
<a href="{{var subscriber.getUnsubscriptionLink()}}">{{var subscriber.getUnsubscriptionLink()}}</a>
```

This only generates this link: `http://www.sitename.com/index.php/newsletter/subscriber/unsubscribe/` without any code and id in URL

The method in `app\code\core\Mage\Newsletter\Helper\Data.php` looks like this

```
public function getUnsubscribeUrl($subscriber)
    {
        return Mage::getModel('core/url')
            ->setStore($subscriber->getStoreId())
            ->getUrl('newsletter/subscriber/unsubscribe', array(
                'id'     => $subscriber->getId(),
                'code'   => $subscriber->getCode(),
                '_nosid' => true
            ));

   }
```

I have tested it many time using test newsletter option
How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: please ans this- http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/100990/getting-wrong-final-price-for-configurable-products

Answer (score 1):

Your call is `subscriber.getUnsubscriptionLink()`, but the function is `getUnsubscribeUrl()` (LINK vs. URL)

Answer (score 1):

I know I am late here but still I want to share solution here.

I am using Magento 1.9.
To add newsletter unsubscribe link in newsletter template here are following steps:

1. Override the core file

> /app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php

by copy in local directory

> /app/code/local/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php

2. Open in editor to edit the code and search the `function sendConfirmationSuccessEmail()`
   replace the code

```
$email->sendTransactional(
    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_IDENTITY),
    $this->getEmail(),
    $this->getName(),
    array('subscriber'=>$this)
);
```

with this

```
$email->sendTransactional(
    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_IDENTITY),
    $this->getEmail(),
    $this->getName(),
    array('subscriber'=>$this, 'unsubscribe' =>$this->getUnsubscriptionLink())
);
```

3. and place this code in email template where you want to use unsubscribe link:

   `<a href="{{var unsubscribe}}">Unsubscribe here</a>`

That's it!

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: please ans this- http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/100990/getting-wrong-final-price-for-configurable-products