# Magento newsletter unsubscribe link not working

Tags: magento-1.9, newsletter

I wanted to add a unsubscribe link to the bottom of the newsletter.
the magento default

> {{var subscriber.getUnsubscriptionLink()}}">{{var
>   subscriber.getUnsubscriptionLink()}}

It generates the link

https://example.com/nl/newsletter/subscriber/unsubscribe/

Which redirects to

https://example.com/nl/newsletter/subscribed#.WR3C02grL4Y

And the user is not unsubscribed from the newsletter.

Answer (score 1):

I never use Magento to send newsletter, you can add this at the bottom of your email template and it should work

```
<a href="{{var subscriber.getUnsubscriptionLink()}}">
{{var subscriber.getUnsubscriptionLink()}}
</a>
```

Comment: It's not working. It does generate a link 
https://example.com/nl/newsletter/subscriber/unsubscribe/
But the link doesn't unsubscribe the user.

Comment: please see this it may help https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/68331/email-newsletter-unsubscribe-link-is-not-working/83376

Comment: I have looked at that. Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: I checked {{var subscriber.getUnsubscriptionLink()}} Magento 2.2.3 and it renders the link correctly. Unsubscription works as expected

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too with Magento 2.4.2. This solution fixed it here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/33753/commits/dfe2a283b227f20730ecef7a605c8cfd3f1e1897

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This**

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Magento\Newsletter\Model\Queue" type="VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\Queue" />

    <preference for="Magento\Newsletter\Model\Template" type="VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\Template" />

</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Model**

**Queue.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Model;

class Queue extends \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Queue
{
    /**
     * Send messages to subscribers for this queue
     *
     * @param int $count
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     */
    public function sendPerSubscriber($count = 20)
    {
        if ($this->getQueueStatus() != self::STATUS_SENDING &&
            ($this->getQueueStatus() != self::STATUS_NEVER &&
                $this->getQueueStartAt())
        ) {
            return $this;
        }

        if (!$this->_subscribersCollection->getQueueJoinedFlag()) {
            $this->_subscribersCollection->useQueue($this);
        }

        if ($this->_subscribersCollection->getSize() == 0) {
            $this->_finishQueue();
            return $this;
        }

        $collection = $this->_subscribersCollection->useOnlyUnsent()->showCustomerInfo()->setPageSize(
            $count
        )->setCurPage(
            1
        )->load();

        $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateData(
            [
                'template_subject' => $this->getNewsletterSubject(),
                'template_text' => $this->getNewsletterText(),
                'template_styles' => $this->getNewsletterStyles(),
                'template_filter' => $this->_templateFilter,
                'template_type' => self::TYPE_HTML,
            ]
        );

        /** @var \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber $item */
        foreach ($collection->getItems() as $item) {

            $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateOptions(
                ['area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => $item->getStoreId()]
            )->setTemplateVars(
                [
                    'subscriber' => $item,
                    'subscriber_data' => [
                        'unsubscription_link' => $item->getUnsubscriptionLink(),
                    ],
                ]
            )->setFrom(
                ['name' => $this->getNewsletterSenderName(), 'email' => $this->getNewsletterSenderEmail()]
            )->addTo(
                $item->getSubscriberEmail(),
                $item->getSubscriberFullName()
            )->getTransport();

            try {
                $transport->sendMessage();
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\MailException $e) {
                /** @var \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Problem $problem */
                $problem = $this->_problemFactory->create();
                $problem->addSubscriberData($item);
                $problem->addQueueData($this);
                $problem->addErrorData($e);
                $problem->save();
            }
            $item->received($this);
        }

        if (count($collection->getItems()) < $count - 1 || count($collection->getItems()) == 0) {
            $this->_finishQueue();
        }
        return $this;
    }

}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Model**

**Template.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Model;

class Template extends \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Template
{

    /**
     * Retrieve template text wrapper
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTemplateText()
    {
        if (!$this->getData('template_text') && !$this->getId()) {
            $this->setData(
                'template_text',
                __(
                    'Follow this link to unsubscribe <!-- This tag is for unsubscribe link  -->' .
                    '<a href="{{var subscriber_data.unsubscription_link}}">Unsubscribe' .
                    '</a>'
                )
            );
        }

        return $this->getData('template_text');
    }
}
```

Use in Newslatter Email Template : `<a href="{{var subscriber_data.unsubscription_link}}">Unsubscribe</a>`

Reference Link : https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/33753

Answer (score 0):

> **Try this code [Magento 2.4.5-p1]**

Only update your template code like the below:

```
<p><a href="{{var subscriber_data.confirmation_link}}">{{var subscriber_data.confirmation_link}}</a></p>
```

Please clear the cache after updating the template.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Default Magento Issue in some of the versions.

`{{var subscriber.getUnsubscriptionLink()}}">{{var subscriber.getUnsubscriptionLink()}}` doesn't return any unsubscribe link.

In Order to get our way around, passing the unsubscribe link in a explicit way.
By Overriding the **Vendor/Magento/Module-Newsletter/Model/Queue.php** and passing the unsubscribe link to the *Collection Item* of the `sendPerSubscriber()` method.

`$item->setData('yourCustomVariable', $item->getUnsubscriptionLink());`

**Create Newsletter template in the Admin with** `{{var subscriber.yourCustomVariable}}`